# Adding "delta" as a synonyme for "delta-air-lines"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

[delta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) is a newly created tag at Travel.SE and is being used like a synonyme for  [delta-air-lines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-air-lines).

I suggest we make them real synonymes, unless anyone can think of any other use for [delta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta).

---

*I don't have enough rep to create the synonyme.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done and done. Thanks!

I briefly wondered about 'delta' as in difference between, but ... after 8 years if we haven't had a use for it, I suspect we can deal with that if it comes up.